# Exact same hashing in java as PHP with salt? (SHA-256)

Tags: java, php, sha256

I can simply hash in PHP with a salt:

```
$orig_pw = "abcd";
$salt = 5f8f041b75042e56;
$password = hash('sha256', $orig_pw . $salt);
```

(This is not how I implement it, this is just an example. Salt is different for everyone)

And with this, the stored password is:

```
bc20a09bc9b3d3e1fecf0ed5742769726c93573d4133dbd91e2d309155fa9929
```

But if I try to do the same in Java, I get a different result. I tried `String password = "abcd";`

```
byte[] salt = hexStringToByteArray("5f8f041b75042e56");

try {
    System.out.println(new String(getHash(password, salt)));
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the two methods:

```
public byte[] getHash(String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(salt);
        try {
            return digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
```

The result is:

```
/¬1¶ĆĽëüFd?[$?¶»_9ËZ»ç¶S‘ĘĹ—×©
```

Which coded to hex is not even close to it:

```
2fac31b6434c14ebfc46643f5b243fb6bb5f39cb5abb10e7b65391454c97d7a90d0a
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the order being swapped, it looks like in PHP you're treating the salt value as a literal string to be appended to the password, while in Java you do a hex conversion of the salt first and then use the resulting bytes to update the `MessageDigest`. This will obviously yield different results. Looking only at the salt:

**PHP:** Salt -> To bytes (literal) -> SHA-256
**Java:** Salt -> To bytes (unhex) -> SHA-256

I just tried your Java code, and it's absolutely fine. I also tried to hash the same value in PHP as in Java and it gave me identical results.

The Java equivalent to your PHP code would be:

```
String password = "abcd";
String salt = "5f8f041b75042e56";

try {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

    return digest.digest((password + salt).getBytes("UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    return null;
}
```

After hexing the bytes it returns the following result:

```
60359BC8A0B09898335AA5A037B1E1B9CE3A1FE0D4CEF13514901FB32F3BCEB0
```

And in PHP doing:

```
<?
echo hash('sha256', "abcd"."5f8f041b75042e56");
?>
```

Returns exactly the same.

Comment: I don't understand every word (not english). So should I change the salt in java? (like: byte[] salt = "5f8f041b75042e56".getBytes();) Also, how can I swap them in java?

Comment: I don't know what your actual PHP code looks like (the code you posted won't run because of the bare hex string). It seems however that you're hashing `"abcd"."5f8f041b75042e56"`. To do the equivalent in Java, you would have to do `("password" + "salt").getBytes("UTF-8")` and then digest that.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the code, that's not how it's implemented. The actual code gets a random number: $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
digest.update(salt);
digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

is equivalent to:

```
hash('sha256', $salt . $orig_pw);
```

So the hash and salt are swapped. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, they are swapped i think. (And if is possible, keep it that way)

Comment: You can't just swap them, the input has to be the same in PHP and in Java.

Comment: I meant keep it swapped in php and swap it in java too.